# How to play a sound effect along a morse code letter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, morse-code

so I am coding a Morse Code translator in C# visual studio, it takes input text then saves it as morse code to a text file. However, I am attempting to code to play the sound for each letter, achieving this by I have the .wav file for each letter in my visual studio project. In this code, I have a translator that matches the english letter words to their respective morse code letters, I am attempting for the respective .wav file to play alongside the translated letter.

Here is the code:

```
private static void InitializeDictionary()
{
    _morseAlphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, string>()
                               {
                                   {'a', ".-"},
                                   SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__A_morse_code.wav");
    snd.Play();
    { 'b', "-..."},
                                   {'c', "-.-."},
                                   {'d', "-.."},
                                   {'e', "."},
                                   {'f', "..-."},
                                   {'g', "--."},
                                   {'h', "...."},
                                   {'i', ".."},
                                   {'j', ".---"},
                                   {'k', "-.-"},
                                   {'l', ".-.."},
                                   {'m', "--"},
                                   {'n', "-."},
                                   {'o', "---"},
                                   {'p', ".--."},
                                   {'q', "--.-"},
                                   {'r', ".-."},
                                   {'s', "..."},
                                   {'t', "-"},
                                   {'u', "..-"},
                                   {'v', "...-"},
                                   {'w', ".--"},
                                   {'x', "-..-"},
                                   {'y', "-.--"},
                                   {'z', "--.."},
                                   {'0', "-----"},
                                   {'1', ".----"},
                                   {'2', "..---"},
                                   {'3', "...--"},
                                   {'4', "....-"},
                                   {'5', "....."},
                                   {'6', "-...."},
                                   {'7', "--..."},
                                   {'8', "---.."},
                                   {'9', "----."}
                               };
}
```

However, the code generates this error:

'SoundPlayer' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Any advice how to format this correctly? Thanks very much.

Edited code

```
     {'a', new MorseMapping(".-", 
      
     @"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__A_morse_code.wav")},
_morseAlphabetDictionary['a'].Player.Play();
```

Comment: You put that code into the collection initializer. That's not how those work. You need to have either another dictionary that relates chars to sound or have a datastructure in that dictionary that relates chars to morse-code _and_ sound. _Playing_ the sound is on a completely other page.

Comment: can your soudnplayer play only 1 file? one instance one file?

Comment: welcome to stack Overflow. You might consider to mark an answer that helped you to solve your problem as accepted. I am also talking about your other questions that you have posted on StackOverflow. [Here is shown how to do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to create and insert a `SoundPlayer` into the initialization block of the dictionary. This is why you get the error, because the dictionary expects a char-string pair there. Put it before the declaration of the dictionary:

```
SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\keife\source\repos\MorseCodeTranslator\MorseCodeTranslator\AnyConv.com__A_morse_code.wav");
_morseAlphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, string>()
                           {
                               {'a', ".-"},
```

The second thing is that I would advise you to map not only the morse letter but already the path to the corresponding wav file or the entrire soudnplayer. You can use a custom class for it

```
public class MorseMapping
{
    public string MorseLetter {get; set;}
    public SoundPlayer Player {get; set;}

    public MorseMapping(string letter, string filePath)
    {
         this.MorseLetter = letter;
         this.Player = new SoundPlayer(filePath):
    }
}
```

Now you can use this class in the dictionary:

```
_morseAlphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, MorseMapping>()
                           {
                               {'a', new MorseMapping(".-", @"C:\myPath\fileForA.wav")},
                               //.. here goes  the rest
                           }; // end of initialization block!!!
```

Now if you want to play a sound for `a` you extract your Mapping and use the soundplayer:

```
_morseAlphabetDictionary['a'].Player.Play();
```

EDIT: very important!: call the player outside of the initialization block of the dictionary. Don't put any other code except the dictionary items init inside the intialization block!

Comment: I just inserted that under "edited code" but it now returns this error:  'string' does not contain a definition for 'Player' and no accessible extension method 'Player' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? Thanks very much. Why is this?

Comment: @KeiferBly, Mongzhu's solution is very good. Based on my test, there is no error. Can you share your error picture?

Comment: @KeiferBly did you change the type of your dictionary to `= new Dictionary<char, MorseMapping>()` ? or is it still `new Dictionary<char, string>()` as in your original version?

Comment: Yes. As requested, here is the photo. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CXH-ck24_YZ63tZG2OnFhyLRaBZNd_7U/view?usp=sharing Sorry would not allow me to attach to comments. The "player.play" is where this error is showing up. Thanks very much.

Comment: @KeiferBly apparently you did not read the very first part of my answer. You cannot put this line into the `{....}` it is the initialization block of the dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you showed in the comment, you can try the following code to solve the problem.

Please don't call method `Player.Play()` in the dictionary.

Code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntializeDictionary();
        }

        private static void IntializeDictionary()
        {
            Dictionary<char, MorseMapping> _morseAlphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, MorseMapping>()
            { {'a',new  MorseMapping(".-", @"C:\myPath\fileForA.wav") }
               //.. here goes  the rest
            };

            _morseAlphabetDictionary['a'].Player.Play();
        }

        public class MorseMapping
        {
            public string MorseLetter { get; set; }
            public SoundPlayer Player { get; set; }

            public MorseMapping(string letter, string filePath)
            {
                this.MorseLetter = letter;
                this.Player = new SoundPlayer(filePath);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked! Will let know if any more issues. THanks

Comment: @KeiferBly, I don't have any other problem. If your problem has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.